# Best way to AJAX load a partial or big chunk of HTML in python and Flask?

Tags: python, ajax, flask

I'm trying to hide a big chunk of a web page with sensitive information behind an AJAX call protected by a verification code.

Whats the best way to mount/send the payload? Its not practical to have it directly in the return statement. How can I, say send a file with the html in it? What if I want to have python calls in it as well?

So for example, if this is the request?

```
`@app.route('/_return_code', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def show_code():
    if request.method == "POST":
        return [some a big chunk of html]`
```